# SQL Exception when fetching using query list(); in java

Tags: hibernate

I have a query in SQL which fetch a list of entity objects. **I am fetching and storing them in list of type entity classes.** I am getting an SQL Exception - the data types of the operands for the operation "=" are not compatible.. SQLCODE=-401, SQLSTATE=42818, DRIVER=3.62.56

The query runs fine in Local And Unix environment using SQL Editor or SQl Explorer.

```
public List<AssessmentApplicationEntity> getActiveAssessmentsForApplication() throws UnableToFetchException
{
    List<AssessmentApplicationEntity> list = null;

    String sqlQueryStr = "select AAT.ID, AAT.Application_id,AAT.RISK_ASSESSMENT_ID , AAT.ARCHIVE, AAT.USER, AAT.CREATED_DATE, AAT.ASSET_UNIQUE_ID " +
    "from assessment_application_table AAT join risk_assessment_table RAT on AAT.RISK_ASSESSMENT_ID = RAT.risk_assess_id "+
    " where RAT.status = 'A' and RAT.ISRAENDREP_ISSDT is null and AAT.ARCHIVE IS NULL and RAT.ARCHIVE IS NULL group by AAT.ID, AAT.Application_id, "+
    "AAT.RISK_ASSESSMENT_ID , AAT.ARCHIVE, AAT.USER, AAT.CREATED_DATE, AAT.ASSET_UNIQUE_ID ";

    Session session = this.getHibernateSession();
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQueryStr);
    sqlQuery.addEntity(AssessmentApplicationEntity.class);

    try {           
        list = sqlQuery.list();
```

Comment: What's the collation of _RAT.status_?

Comment: It is varchar. I found the problem. Thank you.